# Bubble sort Descending and Ascending in C won't sort

Tags: objective-c, c, bubble-sort

I'm giving a user choices to whether sort the elements in ascending or descending order. I know my code can sorts the elements right but somewhere in main I think I'm making mistake in calling my function to print the ascending/descending element in their proper order. Or do I have to have another if statement like I have in the `bubble_sort` function? I need to make it so the Main function prints the final results to the user. Here's the output I'm getting: 
***Enter number of elements
3
Enter 3 integers
43
7
90
Enter sort order
Please enter A for ascending or D for descending order
d
Sorted list in descending order:
43
7
90***

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubble_sort(long [], char n);

int main()
{
    long array[100], n, c;

    printf("Enter number of elements\n");
    scanf("%ld", &n);

    printf("Enter %ld integers\n", n);
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        scanf("%ld", &array[c]);

    printf("Enter sort order\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter A for ascending or D for descending order\n");
    scanf("%ld", &n);
    bubble_sort(array, n);
    printf("Sorted list in descending order:\n");
    for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
    {
        printf("%ld\n", array[c]);
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void bubble_sort(long list[], char n)
{
    long c, d, temp;

    if(n=='a' || n=='A')
    {
        for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
        {
            for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
            {
                if (list[d] > list[d+1])
                {
                    temp = list[d];
                    list[d] = list[d+1];
                    list[d+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(n=='d' || n=='D')
    {
        long c, d, temp;

        for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
        {
            for (d = 0 ; d > n - c - 1; d++)
            {
                if (list[d] < list[d+1])
                {/* Swapping */
                    temp = list[d];
                    list[d] = list[d+1];
                    list[d+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Here I added a swap function just so the ascending/descending logic is more efficient. But I seem to mixed up use of the variables which I think is a big problem. Would anyone point out and help me understand where and why I'd need to use those variables? Thanks much!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubble_sort(int list[], int n, char c);
void swap(int x, int y, int array[]);
int main()
{
    int array[100], j, i;
    char c;
    printf("Enter number of elements\n");
    scanf("%d", &j);

    printf("Enter %d integers\n", j);
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    printf("Please enter A for ascending or D for descending order\n");
    scanf("%s", &c);

    bubble_sort(array, j, i);
    printf("Sorted list in descending order:\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < j ; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void bubble_sort(int list[], int n, char c)
{
    int i, j;

    if(c=='a' || c=='A'){
        for (i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++){
            for (j = 0; j < (n - i) - 1; j++){
                if (list[i] > list[j])
                {
                    swap(i, j, list);                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(c=='d' || c=='D') {
        for (i = 0 ; i < ( n - 1 ); i++) {
            for (j = 0 ; j > (n - i) - 1; j++) {
                if (list[i] < list[j])
                {
                    swap(i, j, list);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void swap(int x, int y, int array[])
{
    int hold; //temp hold a number

    hold = array[x];
    array[x] = array[y];
    array[y] = hold;
}
```

Comment: You use n as length and choice at the same time, but that are 2 different values.

Comment: oh cut-n-paste!, thou art a cruel and heartless wench.

Comment: @WhozCraig what are you talking about? I've been working on this project for couple hours. Please be polite!

Comment: @pointing_Stack in no way was anything I said critical of **you**. It was simply a declaration that sometimes cut-n-paste leads to defects we don't even think about. And in that hour it is unfortunate it didn't strike you odd that to sort a sequence of some length `N` based on some option choice  C your sort function would need the sequence, the sequence length N , *and* the chosen option C. Given your function only takes two parameters, one of those is clearly missing. Debugging would help *immensely* in noticing that if you don't see it while visually reviewing your code.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for clarifying your comment. It's now helpful :)

Comment: @pointing_Stack no worries. Vlad has an answer that is definitely worth the uptick and "correct" answer selection. It is the root of the issue and I'm glad you worked it out or at least better understand the problem. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statements

```
printf("Please enter A for ascending or D for descending order\n");
scanf("%ld", &n);
```

you are overwritting the value stored in n that before these statements denoted the number of the elements in the array. You should declare one more variable of type char and use it for this code snippet.

Also the sort function should be declared as

```
void bubble_sort(long list[], int n, char c );
```

where n is the array size and c is either 'A' or 'D'

**EDIT:** Your new code contains many typos. Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap( int x, int y, int array[] )
{
    int hold; //temp hold a number

    hold = array[x];
    array[x] = array[y];
    array[y] = hold;
}

void bubble_sort( int list[], int n, char c )
{
    int i, j;

    if ( c == 'a' || c == 'A' )
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < n - 1; i++ )
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++ )
            {
                if ( list[j] > list[j+1] )
                {
                    swap( j, j + 1, list);                
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ( c=='d' || c=='D' ) 
    {
        for ( i = 0 ; i < n - 1; i++ ) 
        {
            for ( j = 0 ; j < n - i - 1; j++ ) 
            {
                if ( list[j] < list[j+1] )
                {
                    swap( j, j + 1, list);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int array[100], j, i;
    char c;

    printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    scanf( "%d", &j);

    printf( "Enter %d integers\n", j );
    for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ ) scanf( "%d", &array[i] );

    printf("Please enter A for ascending or D for descending order: ");
    scanf( " %c", &c );

    printf( "%c\n", c );

    bubble_sort( array, j, c );

    printf( "Sorted list in the selected order:\n" );
    for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", array[i] );
    }
    puts( "" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Spasibo za obesneniye! I made the changes, but I think my biggest problem in this overall is to correctly use the variables. Can you please check my edit? It's still giving the same outputs.

Comment: I just added them :) Khorosho, obyazatel'no proveryu!

Comment: @pointing_Stack This statement scanf("%s", &c);
 is already invalid. You have to use format specifier %c. And the function has to be called as bubble_sort(array, j, c);

Comment: I did make those changes, and now it won't even ask for A/D choices. I think I'm messing up something bigger here which is hard for me to see.

Comment: @pointing_Stack The format for reading character shall include a blank after the first quote: scanf( " %c", &c );

Comment: I can now see my mistakes! Thank you so much for your time and afford!